# Windows 7 cannot recognize USB controller 

Tags: windows-7, usb

I have a new desktop with Windows 7 installed, but after the installation I found that Windows 7 did not install a USB controller driver for me (an exclamation mark is shown next to the USB controller in Device Manager). This prevents any connected USB devices from working.

Where can I get the the default Windows 7 USB controller driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default Windows 7 USB Controller Driver should be installed. You may need to find the driver for your specific hardware component. Visit your manufacturers website to see if you can get an updated install.

Comment: But I found that the default Windows 7 USB Controller Driver is not installed in my case . Even I install the driver for the USB device , the window 7 still cannot detect it as there are no USB Controller Driver . Can I get this default Windows 7 USB Controller Driver  from the installation CD or where can I download it?

Comment: Yes . Finally I found that my window 7 installation disk is some beta version and does not include the USB Controller Driver